# Issue is update props with onchange(@change) in vue js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to update the data when doing on-change from the select box. Currently, i am able to the first time with the button click and also with on change. But I am not able to when doing the on-change multiple times.

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <select v-model="selectedemp" @change="filterempdata($event.target.value)">
                <option value="">Select emp/option>
                <option v-for="option in empfilterlist" v-bind:value="option.value" v-bind:key="option.value">{{ option.text }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <empView v-if='loaded' :empDetails='empData'></empView>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" v-on:click="getEmpDetails">Fetch Data</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Javascript part:

```
    data () {
      return {
        loaded: false,
        empData: {},
        empfilterlist: [
            { text: 'Department', value: '1' },
            { text: 'Status', value: '2' },
        ],
        selectedemp: '',
    }
},
methods: {
    filterempdata: function (selectedoption) {
        console.log('Onchange value - ' + selectedOption)
        Vue.set(this.empData, 'Department', selectedoption)
    },

    getEmpDetails: function () {
        this.$http.get('http://localhost:7070/getemmdata')
            .then((response) => {
            this.empData = response.data
            this.loaded = true
        },
        response => {
            console.log('test' + JSON.stringify(response))
        }
    )   
}
```

Child component javascript code:

```
    export default {
    name: 'empView',
    props: ['empDetails'],
    data () {
        return {
            empid: this.empDetails.id,
            empname: this.empDetails.name
        }
    },
    watch: {
        empDetails: function (changes) {
            console.log('data updated ' + JSON.stringify(changes))
            this.empid = changes.id
            this.empname = changes.name
            this.department = changes.Department
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your data has **emptData** but in your methods you are referring to **empData**. Typo?

Comment: @Steve Holgado Yes that is typo. sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't complete. I've edited it and created a small example. 
You call `Vue.set(this.empData, 'Department', value);`. Maybe there is a 
spelling mistake, because I can't find `this.empData`.

**UPDATE:** Don't use camelCase for your html attributes (Use `:empdetails` instead of `:empDetails`). I've removed the on change attribute and replaced it with a computed values.

```js
const empview = {
  name: 'empview',
  template: '<div>ID: {{empid}} TITLE: {{empname}} RANDNUM: {{random}}</div>',
  props: ['empdetails'],
  computed: {
    empid() {
      return this.empdetails.id;
    },
    empname() {
      return this.empdetails.name;
    },
    random() {
      return this.empdetails.random;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    workflowDetails(changes) {
      console.log('data updated ' + JSON.stringify(changes))
      this.empid = changes.id
      this.empname = changes.name
      this.department = changes.Department
    }
  }
};


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    empview
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loaded: false,
      empData: {},
      empfilterlist: [
        { 
          text: 'Department', 
          value: '1' 
        },
        { 
          text: 'Status', 
          value: '2' 
        }
      ],
      selectedemp: ''
    }
  },
  watch: {
    // triggers on change
    selectedemp(value) {
      // your filterempdata() code
      console.log(value);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    /*getEmpDetails() {
      this.$http.get('http://localhost:7070/getemmdata')
        .then((response) => {

        this.empData = response.data
        this.loaded = true
      }, (response) => {
        console.log('test' + JSON.stringify(response))
      })
    }*/
    getEmpDetails() {
      console.log('getEmpDetails()');
      const data = this.empfilterlist.filter((emp) => emp.value == this.selectedemp)[0];

      if(data) {
        this.empData = {
          id: data.value,
          name: data.text,
          random: Math.random()
        };

        this.loaded = true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body class="container">

  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <div class="row">
        <select v-model="selectedemp">
          <option value="">Select emp</option>
          <option v-for="option in empfilterlist" :value="option.value" :key="option.value">{{option.text}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <empview v-if='loaded' :empdetails='empData'></empview>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" @click="getEmpDetails">Fetch Data</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have updated the typo. The problem still persists, I am not able to get the value in child component when I do on-change continuously.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hope this will help. Replace `getEmpDetails` with your ajax call. @krrr25

Comment: You can try your code snippet by changing the drop-down continuosly and click fetch data button. it is not firing from seconde time. First time only it's filtering.

Comment: Added a watch method and a random number to check the data change.

Comment: @krrr25 Ok. I've used computed values now. The error was that the initial data only set once when the component did mount and never got triggered again to change it. You also can use `{{empdetails.id}}` and remove `data`, `computed` or `watch` completely.